# Tokenising Sentences in NLP, Python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I have a Dataset with column 'Text' which contains 2851 Sentences and I want to tokenise them all for implementing Bag of Words in NLP.
I tried using the loc function but did not work, Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Hi Pranav. Can you show your dataset once?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nltk` to tokenize the sentences and apply it to your dataset. I'm not sure what your dataset looks like, but here's an example with `pandas`.

```python
    >>> import pandas as pd
    >>> from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
    
    >>> s = "Hey! Look! It's a sentence."
    >>> word_tokenize(s)
```

```
    # Output
    ['Hey', '!', 'Look', '!', 'It', "'s", 'a', 'sentence', '.']
```

```python
    >>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["first", "second", "third"],
            "Text": ["This is the first sentence.",
                     "This is the second sentence.",
                     "Hey! Look! It's a third one."],})
    >>> df
```

```
    # Output
        Name    Text
    0   first   This is the first sentence.
    1   second  This is the second sentence.
    2   third   Hey! Look! It's a third one.
```

```python
    >>> df['Text'].apply(word_tokenize)
```

```
    # Output
    0    [This, is, the, first, sentence, .]
    1    [This, is, the, second, sentence, .]
    2    [Hey, !, Look, !, It, 's, a, third, one, .]
    Name: Text, dtype: object
```